# JavaScript multipage form onbeforeunload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am putting together a quiz system using the multipage form jQuery script and I would like to be able to warn the user if tries to close the page. I managed to do this just fine using the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        return 'Sure you want to close the page?';
    };
});
```

My problem is that when I try to submit the form and post the results I get the warning asking me if I want to navigate away from this page. This is the code:

```
$('#quizForm').formwizard({
    validationEnabled: true,
    focusFirstInput : true,
    formOptions: {
        beforeSubmit: window.onbeforeunload = null,
        resetForm: true
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

LE: I created this fiddle maybe someone can help me out, I am running out of ideas.

http://jsfiddle.net/awLYY/5/

Comment: could you try `window.onbeforeunload = function() {},` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275983/cancel-onbeforeunload-event-handler

Comment: Same thing unfortunately

Comment: I am starting to think that it might be related to the beforeSubmit function ... I don't think it's firing at all or maybe not before the submit part

Answer (score 0):

first, you don't need to wait for the DOM to be ready in order to attach an `onbeforeunload` handler.

second, since the `onbeforeunload` is a function, you can choose wither to return a string or return nothing in case you're submitting some data to the server

```
var isFormBeingSubmitted = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if( isFormBeingSubmitted ) {
        return;
    }
    return 'Sure you want to close the page?';
};

// now before you submit your form, just enable the isFormBeingSubmitted 
$('#quizForm').formwizard({
    validationEnabled: true,
    focusFirstInput : true,
    formOptions: {
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            isFormBeingSubmitted = true;
            return true;
        },
        resetForm: true
    }
});
```

Comment: I got the first part about the DOM but I am not sure how will the code you provided fit with the code that I have, could you please elaborate.

Comment: updated it according to [formwizard](https://github.com/thecodemine/formwizard) docs.

Comment: I tried that already but it's the same behavior. I changed the  function() {isFormBeingSubmitted = true;} with alert(Message) and I got the popup as soon as the page loaded and I didn't get to the submit part so I think it's something related to the formwizard script ...

Comment: from [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm), i guess the `beforeSubmit` should return true in order to proceed.

Comment: It should but for some unknown reason is firing up onLoad instead of waiting for the submit action. Thanks

Comment: I am also just realizing that I am using jQuery version 1.9.1 but formwizard plugin needs the 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, all I had to do was to add to the formwizard options:

```
formPluginEnabled: true
```

Now everything is working fine. Thanks